# C++ Struct - Define Minimum Size

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management

Is there a C++ (or MSVC) method of automatically padding a struct to a minimum size? For example, imagine the following pseudo-code:

```
#pragma pad(256) // bytes
struct SETUPDATA {
  int var1;
  double var2;
};

where sizeof(SETUPDATA) = 256 bytes
```

The goal here being, during development this struct's members can change without changing the footprint size at runtime.

Comment: Bill Gates once said that 640k would be enough... :)

Comment: You can try wrapping it in a union with a `char[256]`.

Comment: Union doesn't prevent the size from getting larger, use static_assert() to verify it didn't change.

Comment: You won't want to use an int in this scenario.  The size is not guaranteed to be 32 bits.  You'd want to use an int32_t

Comment: I think this is an idea, changing members without changing the footprint at runtime?  This is just... a bad idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a union

```
struct SETUPDATA {
    union { struct your_data; char [256]; }
}
```

or something like this. This ensures it's at least 256 but only as long as your_data is not larger.

You can also add a simple assert after that just does a compiler check `assert(sizeof(struct SETUPDATA) == 256)`

Comment: This should play - it even seems that VS2008 allows me to use anonymous structs too which simplifies things.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to inherit from your "real" structure and use `sizeof()` to make up the padded structure, for example:

```
struct blah_real
{
    int a;
};
struct blah : public blah_real
{
private:
    char _pad[256 - sizeof(blah_real)];
};
```

You could use `#ifdef DEBUG` to only do this in the debug build and just use the real structure in release build.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you have ot ask yourself is *why* your application cares if the `struct` size changes. That indicate fragility to future changes and your design may be better served by instead allowing the application to seamlessly work in the face of struct size changes.

Perhaps you're trying to serialize the data directly and don't want to face changes in the format, but in that case you're *already* tying yourself to one specific representation of the structure in memory. For example support the size of one of the builtin-type members changes due to a compiler upgrade or options.

But let's say you *really do* want to do this.

Just wrap the data in an impl and pad the real struct:

```
struct SetupData
{
    struct Impl
    {
        int var1;
        double var2;
    };

    Impl impl_;
    unsigned char pad_[256 - sizeof(Impl)];
};
```

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee that the compiler won't insert padding between `impl_` and `pad_`, making the struct bigger than 256 bytes. It could also fail if `sizeof(Impl)` happens to be exactly 256 bytes, since 0-length arrays aren't permitted by the language.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In this instance the core application is 3rd party and I am just writing plug-in modules. For better or worse the application uses structure copies for load/save chains (Embedded applications have different priorities than desktop applications). Because of this, every time I modify the size of the struct it makes saved data unloadable.

Comment: Amazing, a comment second guessing why the person asking wants to do something! There are good reasons to pad a structure to some size, for example to avoid false sharing of cache lines.